# redirected stdin : how to get ALL lines of the incoming request instead of doing multiple "read"

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, socat

THIS QUESTION IS BASH SCRIPT RELATED... the rest is to explain the context.

context : experimentation : create a simple mini webserver with socat instead of apache.

** the test I'm doing is able to achieve TTFB of 10ms compared to 100-200 + with apache for a simple echo "hello world";

-1- I'm able to use socat to bind a script to a port.

-2- from a browser I type https://myip/

-3- the binded script I do read read read..... to get the incoming "headers"....

-4- please note that I'm really good with php, but fairly new to bash scripting.

how to simplify or get ALL lines of the incoming request to a usable array ?

my working socat command

```
socat -d -d -v -v OPENSSL-LISTEN:2096,crlf,reuseaddr,fork,verify=0,pf=ip4,cert=/path/cert.pem,key=/path/key.pem SYSTEM:/path/sotest.sh
```

my .sh

```
read LINE1
read LINE2
....
echo $LINE1 $LINE2
php /path_to_some.php // the php have some echo $a....
```

but some browsers send 25 lines, some 11, etc

QUESTION :
how to get ALL lines into a passable array or argment

*NOTE* this setup is working, so the question is more related to bash script and dealing with the "redirected stdin" that travel from the incoming request to socat to my .sh

Comment: Did you look at the “SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS” section of [bash(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS)?  Did you notice a command called ```readarray```? Did you try it?

Comment: I'm using a mac os 10.15 when I type readarray I get `zsh: command not found: readarray`

Comment: If you get an error message that begins with `zsh:`, then you’re running zsh (and not bash).  Are you running the script in bash?  If so, try ``readarray`` in the script.  (Also, please run `bash --version` and tell us what it says.)  If you are running the script in zsh (or some other shell), edit your question to say so.

Comment: I still get sotest.sh: line 13: readarray: command not found

Comment: To repeat G-Man's question: are you running the script with zsh or bash? You should know what shell interpreter you're using.  (It should be in your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.) I think `array=() ; while read line ; do array+=($line) ; done` would work on both, but there may be better ways depending on the shell.

Comment: when I declare my shebang, the browser don't recognize the output :(

Comment: @frabjous when I do a while loop it cause the script to go without end, I can get the number of line using, maybe I'll try to concoct a for loop

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica+ readarray (in bash) only works if the input file has an EOF, which HTTP requests for the last two decades usually don't (HTTP/1.1 defaults to and prefers 'keepalive') plus HTTP _headers_ are line-oriented but _bodies_ often aren't (e.g. x-www-form-urlencoded). OP: The only correct way to read HTTP>=1.0 headers is line by line until you get an empty (zero-length) line. Note you should expect (but not require) CRLF instead of LF, which in practice on Unix means removing or ignoring the CR. The number of lines will vary not only by program but state. See 2616 or 7231+.

Comment: Without a shebang, it'll probably run as barebones `sh`, which doesn't even officially support arrays (Though it still might because it may be linked to bash or something like that.) I don't see what the browser has to do with the shebang in the script. The shebang shouldn't be in the output, which is all the browser should see. Not sure why you don't just write the script in php if you're better with that. php can read stdin just as well as bash.

Comment: The first line of your script should start with `#!` and then the path of the shell that's going to interpret the script. What have you got?

Comment: I finally re-explored the php built-in server instead of socat + shell + php... https://serverfault.com/questions/1097150/stunnel3-inetd-mode-tls-server-needs-a-certificate-configuration-fail